# What does "invalid consistency" mean?

Tags: transaction, invalid-consistency

I found a bundle, which shows invalid consistency. The Tangle explorere says, it would never confirm.
My suggestion is that the Bundle input value is higher then the overall bundle output value.

But, what did the user do wrong?

Could this happen using the light wallet only as he claims?

[Address](https://thetangle.org/address/MLXCYDWLIYTOHZFXBVJRBY9R9L9LGQWVPQWDXGUKUHDWMJUAHHRD9GONGOAESPCKQKPMPJKUYAZCUXWBD)

[Bundle](https://thetangle.org/bundle/GFBSAGZLXVDZTLSHWHHFGXJOQLKPGXJGEGDNQFFZEAJXFRCVHCWE9FUEZIZFZWHXWPHBKRJADYTI9XQUX)

Comment: I am in the same pickle and came across this post thanks to Alexa.
Is there any chance that I could have it fixed please?
https://forum.helloiota.com/12063/RE-Invalid-consistency#12130 Many thank you for your help.
Richard

Comment: Yes sure we can help you. Just come to discord #help and ping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invalid consistancy means, indeed, input and output are inconsistant. This is seen in the Bundle:
[image: Bundle showing invalid consistancy]

This might be caused by a poor/non-functional connection either between lightwallet and fullnode or between fullnode and neighbors. In this case it was between fullnode and neighbors. So the complete and correct bundle was found on the initially used fullnode.

We solved the issue by a replay bundle api call to the initial fullnode and logging the output. We used the output to broadcast the correct bundle to another, functional fullnode by api call sendTrytes. This solved the issue, without any address reuse.

Results are shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Address with invalid consistancy in Transactionhistory]

Answer (score 1):

you can see it quite easily when you look into one of the three transactions in detail - there you will see that the max bundle index is 3, which means there used to be 4 transactions. Finding and replaying the 4th transaction (probably on a different node) is the only way to solve this without risking address reuse.