# invalid consistency problem

Tags: transaction, invalid-consistency

I am in the same pickle as in this post below:

[What does "invalid consistency" mean?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1552/what-does-invalid-consistency-mean/1557)

Is there any chance that I could have it fixed please?

https://thetangle.org/bundle/ITKZPXYBJAXFPKCUQWUCKZJZQVDTS9DEBPHKZWDQCFGQF9PRCHWSDBXGHIAIHWTUSYQQGITSKDEHKQEKC

https://thetangle.org/address/PCMJFOHKDJHZQARYEXIAGKVEZKYWLV9LQTNNRAW9TUUCORVNODHILQL9EJAVWBTOUUWRK99YOGNFYAFVX

Many thank you for your help. 
Richard

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this bundle is supposed to have 4 transactions, but only 3 of them reached the "rest of the network".

If you still know which node you used to initially broadcast that bundle, log into it and try to rebroadcast or reattach from there.